# The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2 instructions to speed up CPU computations

Tags: linux, tensorflow, time, cpu

I have only cpu machine which is model of Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v4 @ 2.40GHz. I need to speed up elapsed time for running my tensorflow code. While running code, it prints warning messages such as:

```
    tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX512F instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

I installed my python and tensorflow with following:

```
conda create -n  py27tf121 python=2.7
pip install tensorflow=1.2.1
```

I am thinking that this warning can speed up the process but I dont know how to activate these flags

Answer (score 1):

This message means that if you compile TensorFlow from source, you might get better performance. Having said that, compiling from source takes time and effort. If you want to try doing that you might find [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) useful